# Running WLP 8.5.5.1 for ISVs now - what is the latest ISV version?

Tags: websphere-liberty

Does anyone know what the latest version of WLP Runtime for ISVs is?  The only thing I've seen is 8.5.5.9, but that looks like it is about a old.  The WASDEV site talks about Wlp 16.x versions, but I do not think that is legally the same thing.

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest fix pack for WebSphere Liberty at the moment is 16.0.0.4.

This fix pack is now available on the Liberty Core for ISVs site.  You can take another look.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a programming question, but 16.x is the (combined) maintenance stream for 8.5.5 and 9.0.  The old 8.5.5.x and 9.0.0.x are dead ends from a versioning perspective.

You'll need to adress your legal/licensing concerns with someone you have a business relationship with at IBM.